# Using Sails.js with yarn

Tags: sails.js, yarnpkg

When I run `sails new myapp` it generates a `package.json` file and a `/node_modules` directory.  The sails docs say to `cd` in and run `npm install` to get up and running.

I've recently started using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and would like to use it to manage the additional dependencies I add to my sails app.  However, when I run `yarn init` (what I think creates the `yarn.lock` file) it looks like it wants to create my `package.json` again.  And it errors on the entry point question, saying `Cannot convert object to primitive value`.

Should I just stick to vanilla npm?  Can Yarn and Sails play nicely in the sandbox together and share the toys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `$ yarn init` (as well as `$ npm init`) will just initialize your `package.json` file by asking a few questions.

Here you don't need to regenerate your `package.json` but just install your node modules and generate a `yarn.lock` file to lock your modules versions. You can do this by using `$ yarn install` or just `$ yarn`.

Comment: I'm glad it was as simple as skipping the `yarn init`.  I ran `yarn` and am up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip `$ yarn init` as it does the exact same thing as `$ npm init`. `$ yarn install` actually creates the `yarn.lock` file. Unlike npm, yarn actually respects the `engines` property in a package.json file. If you run into this you can use `$ yarn install --ignore-engines`.